# Can I use a named pipe binding in a WCF service that supports multiple clients?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I have been doing some reading in preparation for  starting my first WCF project and have come across this statement in Juval Lowy's book(Programming WCF Services):

> In WCF, services that use IPC can only accept calls from the same
> machine. Consequently, you must specify either the explicit local
> machine name or localhost for the machine name, followed by a unique
> string for the pipe name:
>
> net. pipe: //localhost/MyPipe
>
> **You can open a
> named pipe only once per machine, so it is not possible for two named
> pipe addresses to share a pipe name on the same machine.** I

Does this mean that I can only have one client connection per endpoint if I use a named pipe binding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can have multiple connections. A pipe is similar to a TCP connection: the server has an address (IP + port), and multiple clients can connect to it (with their own IP + port). You can have as many quadruples `<SIP, SPort, CIP, CPort>` as the server can handle. A similar thing happens with pipes - the server pipe name will be unique (based on the name), but the client "endpoint" has a different name (likely a Guid), and it's the pair `<SName, CName>` which needs to be unique, so you can have `<SName, CName1>`, `<SName, CName2>`, `<SName, CName3>`, ...

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one host per endpoint but you can have multiple client connecting to the same endpoint.